# Open application using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I want to open an application using AppleScript.
I know the following is used to open an application:

```
tell application "<AppName>" to activate
```

I also tried using "set frontmost of process".

However, this doesn't work with the application that I want to open. 
When the application's window is opened in the background "tell application" brings it to the forefront. On the other hand, if the window is closed, nothing happens.
I think it is because the application is running as an agent app with "LSUIElement" set to "true". This application is run by launchctl at system start.

Is there anyway to open such application?
The problem can be reproduced with "Box" application.

Looking forward for your kind replies.

Update:
I noticed the following log messages in the log file when I manually open the app.

```
ERR [main-thread](118)home view will appear
ERR [main-thread](121)UI is already loaded
ERR [main-thread](34)websecurity viewWillAppear
ERR [main-thread (1818)applicationWillbecomeActive
```

However, only the last message appear in the log through AS. So I guess I have to find how other 3 log messages were invoked.

Comment: Since I don't have anything named "Box" installed, does this mystery application have a scripting command to open a new window?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. The "Box" can be downloaded at https://www.box.com/resources/downloads.

The website doesn't say anything about scripting commands and it doesn't provide scripting dictionary. Checked with Script Editor.

Comment: Which product are you use here, Box Drive for Mac, Box Tools for Mac, or Box Notes for Mac?

Comment: Hi @user3439894
Thank you for taking your time.
It is Box Drive for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

LSUIElement set to true means that the app will only run as a background app: it can display a window, but it will not appear in the dock or the app chooser, take over the system menu bar, or do any of the other graphical interface things that an app typically does. To see if it's running, open Activity Monitor and search for its name in the list of running apps, or run the following code in AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set procs to name of every process
    if procs contains "<AppName>" then
        say "Whoo Hoo!"
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: This code can be used to check whether the process is running not to display the window. The problem is that the process doesn't answer to "activate".
Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @rsanda: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that displaying the window was the goal; that wasn't clear from your post (normally background tasks do other things, and panels are secondary). I'll take a look at your 'box' app.

Comment: @rsanda: I installed Box Drive, and I'm trying to figure out which 'Window' you're talking about. Box Drive is integrated into the Finder: it installs a sidebar icon that open a folder stored at the root level of your drive, and it has a status bar menu that opens a search panel (which you can also open by the control-option-command-space combo). there's also a help window and a link to the Box Drive webpage. which window are you trying to see?

Comment: Better to test whether an application is running like this: `if application id "<bundleid>" is running then..."` where `<bundleid>` is obtained beforehand, one way being a one-off evaluation of `"id of application "<AppName>"`. This doesn't require the app to be scriptable, nor any special permissions, plus works for applications where the process is named differently to the app bundle.